# I use overleaf and the pst-labo package does not work, can someone help me?

Tags: pgfplots, draw, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing, pst-labo

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-labo}

\newcommand{\pstClamp}{
    \colorlet{myfill}{brown!60}
    % potence
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.5,-2.625)(-.25,13)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,8)(1.75,7.75)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,8.25)(-.75,7.5)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.375,7.875){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1.5,8.15)(3,7.6)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,4)(1.75,3.75)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,4.25)(-.75,3.5)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-.375,3.875){.2}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](1.5,4.15)(3,3.6)
    % support elevateur
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](.25,-.25)(3.25,-1.25)(.25,-2.25)(1.25,-2.25)(4.25,-1.25)(1.25,-.25)
    \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill, linearc=.05](4.25,-.25)(1.25,-1.25)(4.25,-2.25)(3.25,-2.25)(.25,-1.25)(3.25,-.25)
    \psline(.25,-1.25)(4.5,-1.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](4.5,-1)(4.75,-1.5)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,0)(4.5,-.25)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](0,-2.25)(4.5,-2.5)
    % base
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=myfill](-1,-2.5)(5,-2.75)
}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5cm}
\psgrid[subgriddiv=1, griddots=10, gridlabels=5pt, gridwidth=0.5pt](0,0)(20,20)
\pstBallon[refrigerantBoulles, glassType=ballon]
\pstClamp

\rput{0}(8,8){\pstClamp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: pstricks needs latex, not pdflatex

Comment: What engine are you using on overleaf? Normally OL runs pdflatex which does not support pstricks. Though there is a package you can load duch that pdflatex runs latex+dvips+ps2pdf in the background. Though, the name of the pa kage eludes me

Comment: And how can I change that? Anyone know?

Comment: You also may compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: change the language with overleaf? because I have 4000 lines written there

Comment: I've already changed it but now includegraphics doesn't work for me, any ideas?

Comment: what did you change to: you should select "latex" (not pdflatex) as the engine in the left side bar

Comment: yes i did that.

Comment: if you want help with an error show the actual error, as text from the log file, not an image of overleaf's summary, that's more or less impossible to debug

Comment: the posted code [runs without error at overleaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtnK7.png)